# Drupal: relating two fields with each other

Tags: drupal, field, contenttype

I have two fields: Supervisor and agent in a new content type. The list of agents depends on the supervisor selected. How can I create such a dependency i.e. each time a different supervisor is selected from a list a new list of agents is set?
Do I need to set up the supervisor and the agents each as nodes and then use entity reference?

How can I set up the dependency in the content type?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot ask for clarification since I'm new here but here goes

Taxonomy terms can be a solution to the problem depending on the amount of information Supervisor and agent holds. If they hold information like phonenumbers, adresses, names etc. then they need a content type. If these are in fact references to users in the system then you need to use those users. If it's just for categorization, taxonomy terms will work just fine.

Set up the Supervisor as the parent term and the agents as children. Then use a widget like this one to handle the input: https://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree
Afterwards you can retrieve and show data based on which term/agent is relevant.

Comment: I tried this approach and it works the way you described it. However, my preference is to use two select lists - one for supervisor, the other for the agent and being able to establish the dependency between both.